# Detect whether a method has been overridden

Tags: c++, inheritance, reflection, polymorphism

#### Question

Given a C++ base class pointer, is there a way to detect whether a certain virtual method has been overridden?

#### Background

I'm writing an interpreter for a little language.  I have a base class to represent values with specializations for the various value types.  Here's a simplified example:

```
class Value {
  public:
    virtual bool CanBeString() const { return false; }
    virtual std::string GetAsString() const {
      throw std::logic_error("Value cannot be represented as a string.");
    }

    virtual bool CanBeInt() const { return false; }
    virtual int GetAsInt() const {
      throw std::logic_error("Value cannot be represented as an int.");
    }
};

class StringValue : public Value {
  public:
    bool CanBeString() const override { return true; }
    std::string GetAsString() const override { return m_string; }
  private:
    std::string m_string;
};

class IntValue : public Value {
   public:
     // Even though this is an integer, it can be represented as a string.
     bool CanBeString() const override { return true; }
     std::string GetAsString() const override { /* return string rep of m_int */ }

     bool CanBeInt() const override { return true; }
     int GetAsInt() const override { return m_int; }
   private:
     int m_int;
};
```

The interpreter works with pointers to `Value`s and does type-checking at runtime.  Suppose the interpreter has a value and it needs to execute an operation on it that applies only to ints.  It will first check `pValue->CanBeInt()`.  If true, the interpreter proceeds with `pValue->GetAsInt()` and does the processing.  If the value is not compatible with an int, it reports a type error.

The base implementations of `GetAsXxx` should never be executed.  If one is executed, it means there's a bug in the *interpreter* (it forgot to check the type first).  Those throw statements are to signal me to fix the interpreter; I do *not* want to throw an exception because of a type error in the *code that's being interpreted*.

#### Motivation

In order to make it easier (and less error prone) to add new types to the system, I've been trying to determine if there's a way to eliminate the need for the derived classes to override the `CanBeXxx` by being able to detect if the corresponding `GetAsXxx` method has been overridden.

#### What I've Tried

My specific idea was to change the `CanBeXxx` methods to non-virtual ones defined in the base class that try to compare the member function pointer for the `GetAsXxx` method to the one for `Value::GetAsXxx`.  As in:

```
bool CanBeInt() const { return &GetAsInt != &Value::GetAsInt; }
```

Alas, this doesn't compile because apparently you can't get a member function pointer for a method that's already bound.  Is there a variation on this idea or another approach that would allow for this little slice of reflection?

Comment: Why not use `bool GetAsInt(int &)`?

Comment: @Beta:  `GetAsXxx` may involve expensive conversions for some of the more interesting types.  Type checking happens in a separate pass from the actual processing, and I don't want to invoke conversions just for type checking and then invoke them again when I actually need the value.

Comment: *Why* must type checking happen in a separate pass? This really feels like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Beta:  (1) separation of concerns--generating diagnostics is distinct from evaluation, (2) preference for functional style, (3) interoperability with existing template machinery that marshals values from this hierarchy to free functions that work with plain C++ types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pulling apart member method pointers to do comparisons is compiler-specific, as different compilers handle method pointers differently.  However, there is an alternative design you might consider.  It won't completely eliminate the problem, but it will simplify it a little, while still providing flexibility to add more types in the future:

```
const unsigned int CanBeInt = 1;
const unsigned int CanBeString = 2;
...

class Value {
  private:
    unsigned int flags;
  public:
    Value(unsigned int aflags) : flags(aflags) {}

    unsigned int GetFlags() const { return flags; }

    inline bool CanBeString() const { return (flags & CanBeString); }
    virtual std::string GetAsString() const {
      throw std::logic_error("Value cannot be represented as a string.");
    }

    inline bool CanBeInt() const { return (flags & CanBeInt); }
    virtual int GetAsInt() const {
      throw std::logic_error("Value cannot be represented as an int.");
    }
};

class StringValue : public Value {
  public:
    StringValue() : Value(CanBeString) {}
    std::string GetAsString() const override { return m_string; }
  private:
    std::string m_string;
};

class IntValue : public Value {
   public:
     // Even though this is an integer, it can be represented as a string.
     IntValue() : Value(CanBeInt | CanBeString) {}
     std::string GetAsString() const override { /* return string rep of m_int */ }
     int GetAsInt() const override { return m_int; }
   private:
     int m_int;
};
```

```
if (pValue->CanBeInt()) {
    int val = pValue->GetAsInt();
    ...
}


if (pValue->GetFlags() & CanBeInt) {
    int val = pValue->GetAsInt();
    ...
}
```

```
if (pValue->CanBeString()) {
   std::string val = pValue->GetAsString();
   ...
}

if (pValue->GetFlags() & CanBeString) {
   std::string val = pValue->GetAsString();
   ...
}
```

Another option, like @Beta suggested:

```
class Value {
  public:
    virtual bool GetAsString(std::string &) const { return false; }
    virtual bool GetAsInt(int &) const { return false; }
};

class StringValue : public Value {
  public:
    bool GetAsString(std::string &value) const override { value = m_string; return true; }
  private:
    std::string m_string;
};

class IntValue : public Value {
   public:
     // Even though this is an integer, it can be represented as a string.
     bool GetAsString(std::string &value) const override { value = ...; return true; }
     bool GetAsInt(int &value) const override { value = m_int; return true; }
   private:
     int m_int;
};
```

```
std::string val;
if (!pValue->GetAsString(val))
   throw std::logic_error("Value cannot be represented as a string.");
```

```
int val;
if (!pValue->GetAsInt(val))
   throw std::logic_error("Value cannot be represented as a int.");
```