# Given both types, can I determine if a virtual function have been overridden?

Tags: c++, inheritance, reflection

I am designing a system that is built from a collection of modules.  The base `Module` class has a set of virtual functions that do nothing by default, but can be overridden in derived module classes if they are needed.

For example, one of these functions is `OnUpdate()`.  Currently when an update occurs, I loop through all modules and run this function on each of them.  Of course, this results in many "wasted" calls on any module that does not override the relevant function.

Given that most modules do not override most member functions (and profiling indicates that this is a bottleneck in my system), what I'd prefer to do is keep track of which modules DO override a member function and execute only those.  At the moment, I am planning to keep an extra vector of only those module pointers that need to be run.

My problem is that collecting this information requires me to detect whether or not a module has overridden each member function.  I can do this analysis on module creation when I know the exact derived type that I'm working with, so I think it should be possible, but the test that I expected to work does not.

Here's some simplified detection code that fails:

```
    template <typename T>
    T & AddModule() {
      static_assert(std::is_base_of<Module, T>,
                    "AddModule() can only take module types.");

      // Create the new module and store it.
      auto mod_ptr = std::make_shared<T>();
      modules.push_back(mod_ptr);

      // If the module has OnUpdate() track it!
      // *** This test is not working! ***
      if (&T::OnUpdate != &Module::OnUpdate) {
        on_update_mods.push_back(mod_ptr);
      }

      // ...lots more tests here...

      return *mod_ptr;
    }
```

Is there some other way that I can handle this detection?

I'm also happy to hear alternate ideas for how to achieve my goal.  I definitely want to keep it easy for module writers to simply implement any of the designated functions and have them called as appropriate.

The only other option I've come up with so far is to NOT have the virtual functions in the Module base class and then use SFINAE to detect them in the derived class, followed by wrapping them in lambdas and storing a vector of functors to run.  I think that will work BUT it will be slightly slower (more indirection with the functors) and more error prone (right now if you make a typo in a member function name the override keyword will throw an error...)

This question is, indeed, similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22594748/detect-whether-a-method-has-been-overridden) one, but the solutions provided won't work for me.  The first option requires all working member functions to be identified separately in the constructor, and I may be working with dozens or more, so this is error prone.  The second option has the functions return a bool, but is only relevant when they are run, and I can't run them when they aren't needed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect whether a method has been overridden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22594748/detect-whether-a-method-has-been-overridden)

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but it sounds like this could be solved with better architecture? This sounds like a violation of SOLID principles, specifically the interface segregation principle.

Comment: Those "wasted calls" are ridiculously cheap, and determining whether a virtual function has been overridden, even if it were possible, would probably "cost" as much as making a virtual function call that does nothing. Actually a no-op virtual funciton call would likely to be even much faster, given how modern CPUs work. In other words: no, there's no way to do this, and even if there was, this would be a complete waste of time.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: The checks occur at startup, so only once.  Most of the execution is in triggering these functions, and so MANY of them are run.  I'll try to pull together some examples where I can demonstrate that when there are so many of these calls they actually do make a performance difference.

Comment: Doesn't matter. An unconditional function call will always be faster than some check-and-branch, due to branch prediction. In situations where there's a large number of calls that can benefit from such check, the solution is laughably simple: each virtual function simply needs a calling mechanism of some kind that returns an indication of "am I implemented". The base class returns "no", and all implementation return "yes". The End.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding a solution to this problem that gives me a reasonable speedup.  Specifically, for each virtual member function I keep a bool in the base class indicating if that function has been overridden.  Each of these bools defaults to true, but the base implementation of the member function sets it to false when executed (as this will only be run if the function is NOT overridden).

Periodically I scan through and update my vectors, removing any member functions that have been shown to not exist.

Net result, ~10% speedup with no changes needed to the derived modules themselves.  Not as fast as I hoped for, but given that this is for a piece of scientific software where some runs need to go for a month, shaving a few days off certainly helps.